# Getting wrong values in Jinja2

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I am passing a dictionary from python to my HTML in Django, and then I want to get the value of a particular key. I pass the dictionary in a for loop, and then search for the key using an if statement. If that key is found, print the value.

Below is the dictionary passed:

```
{
    'id': 1, 
    'book': {
        'isbn': '0439554934', 
        'isbn13': '9780439554930', 
        'title': "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone (Harry Potter, #1)",
        'publisher': 'Scholastic Inc', 
        'publishYear': 1997, 
        'publishMonth': 6, 
        'edition': None, 
        'rating': '4.46', 
        'popularity': 25779963, 
        'authors': ['J.K. Rowling'], 
        'genres': ['fiction', 'fantasy', 'young-adult']
    }, 
    'userID': 1, 
    'price': '10.00', 
    'condition': 'New', 
    'image1': '', 
    'image2': '', 
    'image3': '', 
    'image4': '', 
    'image5': '', 
    'comment': ''
}
```

I then want to get the title of the book so below is my code:

```
  {% for key, value in book.items %}
      {% if value.title %}
        <h3> {{value.title}}</h3>
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

However, not only do I get the title, I also get the price and condition printed. Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you iterate over a dict if you know the key? Also `title` will be the key in your loop and not an attribute of value. Why not just `<h3>{{ book.title }}</h3>`? But that does not explain, why you also get the price and condition printed. Actually with this template even the title shouldn't be printed. It is likely not because of the template you posted here.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure why I did it that way, cause at first, book.title was not working. Anyways, after doing it your way again, it worked. and no longer adding the price and condition.

Comment: Okay, so far so good. But I also now got the reason, your code rendered title, price and condition. Those are all strings (the values of the dict `book`). And strings in python are objects that have a method `title()` which returns a copy of that string in title case. And functions are automactically called if rendered in a template. That is why you saw those values.

Comment: Thank you again for clarifying the problem!